# how can use libtorrent4j to download files with a magnetLink?

Tags: java, libtorrent, magnet-uri

I am programming an application for android with java and one of its functionalities is to be able to download books through a magnetLink. The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to do it and I don't have much experience working with magnetLink, torrent and all the P2P stuff.

I am also trying to see if there is any library that can help me and that is specific for MagnetLinks, for now I'm trying libtorrent4j.

If someone could guide me in all this P2P network world it would be very helpful, maybe I don't even need to use external libraries, but I have no idea.